# PHP Calling a Function from Memory

Tags: php, reference

I'm not sure how to word this so please bear with me.

#### Here's the scenario:

(Using: PHP 5.4)
I created a PHP Function to encrypt / decrypt php files, right now I can read in a php source file & encrypt it. I can also decrypt the file again back to original PHP source code so up until this point everything works perfect.. *BUT..*

#### This is my question I need help with: (and a code sample would be nice)

on 'decrypt' $action, I want to decrypt the file into memory and be able to
call the function sayHello(), without writing it to a file (I can already do that) by either using memory or a stream, or something I'm not familiar with.
not even a tmp file, or no $_SESSION.

The whole purpose of this, I am making a custom compiler for my php code
I want to run decrypt($fileName) and be able to call functions or Constants out of it while in memory, and maybe a function to take it outta memory somehow, I will only be using it on files at most like 2kb

If I use a tmp file then there is no sense encrypting it, because they can just use that, defeating the whole purpose, same with $_SESSION. There has to be a way to read a file into memory, include it somehow, and be able to call functions out of it as if it were a regular php file.

example..

#### fileName: test.php (file to be encrypted)

```
function sayHello() {
    echo 'hello world';
}
```

now the file that does the actual encryption / decryption

#### fileName:  compiler.php

```
function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) {
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = 'faj6mZqjGYlUuj6TA4uQz';
    $secret_iv = 'a6ZcFzXKimxogfo6yHBR';
    $noExt = basename($string, ".php"); <br />
    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key); <br />
    // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else get warning
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16); <br />
    if ($action == 'encrypt') {
        $fileName = file_get_contents($string);
        $output = openssl_encrypt($fileName, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        $output = base64_encode($output);
        $output = file_put_contents($noExt."_ENC.php", $output);
    }
    else if ($action == 'decrypt') {
        $fileName = file_get_contents($string);
        $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($fileName), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);

       // Below line works if UnCommented for decrypting to file. (not what i want)
       // $output = file_put_contents("test_ENC_DECRYPTED.php", $output);
       // <== THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CALL A FUNCTION IN MEMORY, NOT FROM FILE
    }
    return $output;
}
```

**`*EDIT:`** Original Code Located here.. (I modified it to accept files)
http://naveensnayak.wordpress.com/2013/03/12/simple-php-encrypt-and-decrypt/

**`*NOTE:`** I don't want to use any other dependencies or 3rd party plug-ins or no compilers or extensions. I want this to be portable & work on any PHP 5.3+ version. I realize I said I want to run decrypt($fileName) and I didn't show code for that file, that is because I am going to break this function down and
only the decrypter is going to be used after files are encrypted.

Comment: Use `eval` to execute the code in the decrypted string.

Comment: Does "I created a PHP Function" possibly mean "copy and pasted" instead? Why don't you simply remove the `file_xyz_contents()` calls then? (The origin source of that very function did not contain the file roundtrips, btw.)

Comment: @Barmar: Thet sounds like a sensible answer. Maybe it should be one?

Comment: @mario.. really, out of everything i wrote, thats what you got outta my question.. didn't you read my note, i think your the 'some' people i was referring to.. and i know what the original source looked like, i modified it for my purposes to see if this can be done.. thank you captain obvious.

Comment: @mario, there ya go.. i added a link to the original code, maybe someone needs just `string` encryption/decryption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use eval:

```
eval(encrypt_decrypt('decrypt', $filename));
```

`eval` executes the code in its argument, just as if it were a file that was loaded.

There are some gotchas, though: if it tries to use variables that reference the script filename, they'll get the script that's doing the decrypting, not the file that contained the encrypted or original decrypted script.

Comment: thank you, i ran the test, had to remove `<?php` and `?>` tags,as per the PHP docs, then encrypt test again.. and it echoed the output from within the encrypted function, so i ran more tests, i created a function that returned $a = "This is within", after eval was called, I could access variables, functions (that have a return value so far), and even arrays. so far so good.. i seem to be able to access everything as if it were an included file..

Comment: (sorry couldnt fit it all in).. i dont understand what you meant by the 'gotchas'? what are my limitations using this method? Also how can i 'unset' or 'destroy' what i loaded into memory using eval? can i create a function to say.. refresh memory?

Comment: Basically, the issue is with scope. When you `eval` the string, it will be executed in the scope of the current file and function. I don't think there's any way to clear it out -- it's no different than if you'd loaded the file with `include`. Of course, it will clear out by itself when the script ends.

Comment: Thank You `Barmar`, i think you solved my problem, i never used `eval`  b4, i looked at it earlier too, didnt think it was what i needed.. i looked at streams, capturing, `http://input`, i rewrote that function like 100 times trying different things. you nailed it.. i'm not trying to compile an entire project, though i prolly could, just certain sections, decrypting on the fly.. my purpose is more like secret constants (non-changeable) by end-user, a plug-in system hiding the links & const's. is there a limit to the amount ?memory? i guess im asking, or encrypted filesize?